# Solovays model vs "traditional" measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question, set-theory

I have just finished my first course in measure theory and I feel I have a good grasp of the concepts of measures, sigma-algebras and the Lebesgue integral. In the next course I am taking there is an exercise regarding the completion of a measure space which is a measure space where every nullset is measurable. As an example of a completion, it is mentioned that we can complete the Borel algebra with respect to the Lebesgue measure to get the Lebesgue algebra. If we accept Solovays axiom we can show that the Lebesgue algebra is the power set of the reals.

These connections seem very intriguing but our dreams are crushed when we realize that we can't use AC if we accept Solovays axiom. In all my undergraduate courses so far, AC has sort of just been a given (Linear algebra: All vector spaces have a basis etc.) but is there a part of measure theory that denies AC and uses the fact that the Lebesgue algebra is the power set of the reals?

Comment: No, there is no part of measure theory that does this.  Only a certain part of set theory.  And maybe some part of category theory?

Comment: @GEdgar I was thinking it might be of use in probability theory somewhere?

Comment: There's a parallel question, which is: "How actually different is analysis in Solovay's model?" The answer is, in many ways, "not very" - although the full axiom of choice fails, most results we actually care about use weaker choice axioms, like *dependent choice*, which do hold in Solovay's model.

Comment: It can be (marginally) interesting if the Cauchy functional equation has only linear solutions. For example, this has consequences for the Pasch axiom in geometry.

Comment: @Noah: And it also depends on what you mean by analysis. Hahn-Banach fails, and a lot of the usual infinite dimensional functional analysis becomes very different.